# How do I increment videoIndex on my video navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

I have a video player that I am trying to control with javascript. It looks like this:

```
<iframe height="309" width="500" frameborder="0" id="video_player" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The video player source is equal to nothing right now. But later I command it to be equal to a youtube link. Also there are two buttons to control what part of the movie. This is where my trouble is. I can traverse the first video that is loaded but not the ones remaining. It is too complicated for me to figure out.

```
<button id="back_btn" style="float:left">Back</button>  
<button id="next_btn" style="float:right">Next</button>
```

After the video player and buttons I add the code that controls it. I used a for loop to generate the video menu. I stored the video data in a multidimensional array. I feel like I'm from outer space when I use the term multidimensional array. Like let's open the multidimensional portal to grab the video data. Then I had to use the module pattern to store the value of i in each event listener I created for each menu item. I made a version of this program without the jQuery library and the code doesn't seem to be much shorter. My noob skills at work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Javascript Video Player and Table of Contents
    var partId = 1;
    var videoIndex = 0;
    var videoPlayer = $("#video_player");
    var videos = new Array(
        ["Dr. Dive Flies a Helicopter",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/8t_cEvjpyp0",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/LbXF4un-b5Y",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/ec27I2F1y7E",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y4b9lMcPx64",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/9BqEkbK9sjA",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/veSPoE3CaTM"],
        ["California Diving Competition",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/dUjKW3aN96k"],
        ["Dr. Dive Diving",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/s2iZ-raCKq0"],
        ["Tom Hairabedian playing his harmonica at age 88!",
         "http://www.youtube.com/embed/jQZbVY4HCzQ"]);
    loadVideo();
    for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            var a = $("<a>").html(videos[i][0]);
            //videoIndex = i;//This will break the script
            a.css("display","block");
            a.css("cursor","pointer");
            a.click(function(){
                videoPlayer.attr("src", videos[i][1]);
            });
            $("#contents").append(a);
        }(i));
    }
    $("#back_btn").click(function(){
        partId--;
        loadVideo();
    });
    $("#next_btn").click(function(){
        partId++;
        //videoIndex++;//I add one to...no
        loadVideo();
    });
    function loadVideo(){
        videoPlayer.attr("src", videos[videoIndex][partId]);
    }
</script>
```

I can only use the next and back buttons on the first video that loads. When I am on any video other than the first and use the next and back buttons it will go back to the first video in the video array.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                //Javascript Video Player and Table of Contents
                var partId = 1;
                var videoIndex = 0;
                var videoPlayer = $("#video_player");
                var videos = new Array(["Dr. Dive Flies a Helicopter","http://www.youtube.com/embed/8t_cEvjpyp0","http://www.youtube.com/embed/LbXF4un-b5Y","http://www.youtube.com/embed/ec27I2F1y7E","http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y4b9lMcPx64","http://www.youtube.com/embed/9BqEkbK9sjA","http://www.youtube.com/embed/veSPoE3CaTM"],["California Diving Competition","http://www.youtube.com/embed/dUjKW3aN96k"],["Dr. Dive Diving","http://www.youtube.com/embed/s2iZ-raCKq0"],["Tom Hairabedian playing his harmonica at age 88!","http://www.youtube.com/embed/jQZbVY4HCzQ"]);
                loadVideo();
                for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
                    (function(i){
                    var a = $("<a>").html(videos[i][0]);
                    //videoIndex = i;//This will break the script
                    a.css("display","block");
                    a.css("cursor","pointer");
                    a.click(function(){
                            videoPlayer.attr("src", videos[i][1]);
                        });
                    $("#contents").append(a);
                    }(i));
                }
                $("#back_btn").click(function(){
                    partId--;
                    loadVideo();
                });
                $("#next_btn").click(function(){
                    partId++;
                    videoIndex=i++;
                    loadVideo();
                });
                function loadVideo(){
                    videoPlayer.attr("src", videos[videoIndex][partId]);
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: I could use a switch statement asking if videoIndex is equal to certain numbers but that would be a lot of work wouldn't it. I designed this to just add video data to the array and it is suppose to work.

Comment: Wait I think I figured it out. I tried this and it worked with 1 line of code. Inside the menu navigation click event handler I said: videoIndex = i; Now when I use my menu it updates the videoIndex. I can't believe I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, slightly more robust script below that cleans up a few problems you might run into.

```
<iframe height="309" width="500" frameborder="0" id="video_player" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
<a href="#" id="back_btn">Back</a>   
<a href="#" id="next_btn">Next</a> 

<div id="contents">&nbsp;</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Keep everything in a single function variable to reduce global impact;
var loadVideo = (function() {


  var videos = [["Dr. Dive Flies a Helicopter","http://www.youtube.com/embed/8t_cEvjpyp0","http://www.youtube.com/embed/LbXF4un-b5Y","http://www.youtube.com/embed/ec27I2F1y7E","http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y4b9lMcPx64","http://www.youtube.com/embed/9BqEkbK9sjA","http://www.youtube.com/embed/veSPoE3CaTM"],["California Diving Competition","http://www.youtube.com/embed/dUjKW3aN96k"],["Dr. Dive Diving","http://www.youtube.com/embed/s2iZ-raCKq0"],["Tom Hairabedian playing his harmonica at age 88!","http://www.youtube.com/embed/jQZbVY4HCzQ"]],
      $videoPlayer = $("#video_player"),  // $ in front of jQuery variables for clarity
      currentVideo = 0, i, l,

  // Increment video index safely
  inc = function() {
    var x = currentVideo + 1;
    if ( x >= videos.length ) {
      x = 0;
    }
    currentVideo = x;
    return currentVideo;
  },

  // Decrement video index safely
  dec = function() {
    var x = currentVideo - 1;
    if ( x < 0 ) {
      x = (videos.length - 1);
    }
    currentVideo = x;
    return currentVideo;
  };


  for(i = 0, l = videos.length; i < l; i++){

    // Use normal anchors, clean up and chain jQuery
    $("<a>").
      html(videos[i][0]).
      css({"display" :"block"}).  // Or add a class and use CSS for this.
      attr("href", "#").  // Makes links work
      data("id", i).  // Save our video index number on the link
      click(function(e) {
       currentVideo = $(this).data("id");  // update current video index
       loadVideo(currentVideo);
        e.preventDefault;  // Prevent default # handling.
      }).
      appendTo('#contents');
  }

  // Go back one video
  $("#back_btn").click(function(e){
    loadVideo( dec() );
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  Go forward one video
  $("#next_btn").click(function(e){
    loadVideo( inc() );
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // fills loadVideo variable with reusable function that takes an video number
  return function(videoNum) {
    var v = videoNum || currentVideo;
    $videoPlayer.attr("src", videos[v][1]);
  };


})();

loadVideo();  // Make it go and load video.
</script>
```